# Pygame's draw function - pixel detail

Tags: python, pygame, draw, pixel, rect

1. How do pygame's Rects geometry definitions (left, right, top, bottom, width, height) work in terms of drawing pixels onto the screen?
2. How does the width affect pygame.draw.rect()

Comment: This is a question and answer site. Your post is not a question at all, and will have to be closed as it is. However, it is possible for you to ask a question, and you yourself provide an answer - that would put your contents in an acceptable format. (And it is ok with the site's purposes).

Comment: So, I'd suggest you do that _fast_ - just paste the relevant part of your code as an answer, then edit the question part, removing most of it and rephrasing it a bit so that the answer-post is appropriate to it - otherwise the question will be closed, and it will be tougher to do that.

Answer (score 0):

With the code below you can use pygame.draw and analyze the result pixel by pixel. Therefore you draw onto a small surface, which is scaled up and then blit onto the screen.

Question 1:

A Rect is defined by its coordinates left, top and its measures
   width, length. When using pygame.draw.rect(Surface, color, Rect,
   width=0), the top-left-pixel of the drawing will have the coordinates
   (left,top). The number of pixels in the width direction of the
   drawing is equal to width of the rectangle, therefore the width
   coordinate of the last pixel is (left + width - 1). The same applies for the height. Therefore the coordinate of the bottom-right-pixel is (left + width - 1, top + height - 1)

TLDR:

- Rect.left returns the x coordinate of the left column of pixels of the drawn rect
- Rect.top returns the y coordinate of the top row of pixels of the drawn rect
- Rect.right returns the x coordinate of the column of pixels next right to the drawn rect
- Rect.bottom returns the x coordinate of the row of pixels next under the drawn rect

```py
#draw onto the small surface here

    #=================================================
    rect = pg.Rect(6, 6, 6, 6)
    pg.draw.rect(surface_small, orange, rect, 0)

    rect = pg.Rect(18, 6, 7, 7)
    pg.draw.rect(surface_small, orange, rect, 0)
    #=================================================
```

[Rectangle example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjjWj.jpg)

Question 2:

The width of the drawn rectangle defines the width of the drawn line. A width of 1 (pixel) results in lines, which exactly matches the outline of the same rectangle drawn with width = 0 (filled rectangle). A width > 1 makes these lines thicker. The drawn rectangle grows bigger than the original rectangle and the "missing corner" appears.

Uneven width:

```py
    #draw onto the small surface here
    #=================================================
    rect = pg.Rect(6, 6, 12, 12)

    pg.draw.rect(surface_small, orange, rect, 5)
    pg.draw.rect(surface_small, black, rect, 1)
    #=================================================
```

[Uneven width example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgsoV.jpg)

Even width:

```py
    #draw onto the small surface here
    #=================================================
    rect = pg.Rect(6, 6, 12, 12)

    pg.draw.rect(surface_small, orange, rect,4 )
    pg.draw.rect(surface_small, black, rect, 1)
    #=================================================
```

[Even width example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWm9o.jpg)

Full Code:

```py
    import sys, pygame as pg

    pg.init()
    SCREEN = pg.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    pg.display.set_caption('getRect.squareHead')
    CLOCK  = pg.time.Clock()

    white =     (255,   255,    255 )
    black =     (0,     0,      0   )
    grey_light =(200,   200,    200 )
    grey_dark = (127,   127,    127 )

    orange =    (255,   96,     0   )

    #fill a surface pixel by pixel with alternating colours
    def fill_alternating (surface, width, height):
        counter = None

        for i in range(width):

            if i%2 == 0: counter = False
            else: counter = True

            for j in range(height):
                if counter: colour = white
                else: colour = grey_light
                if i%6 == 0 and j%6 == 0: colour = grey_dark
                pg.draw.circle(surface, colour, (i,j), 0, 0)
                counter = not counter            

    #big surface to blit onto the screen
    width_main, height_main = 700, 500
    surface_main = pg.Surface((width_main, height_main))
    surface_main.fill(orange)
    rect_main = surface_main.get_rect(center = (399, 299))

    #small surface to enlarge onto the big surface
    scale = 20
    width_small, height_small = int(width_main/scale), int(height_main/scale)
    surface_small = pg.Surface((width_small, height_small))
    surface_small.fill(white)
    fill_alternating(surface_small, width_small, height_small)

    #draw onto the small surface here
    #=================================================



    #=================================================

    #scale the small surface onto the main surface
    pg.transform.scale(surface_small, (width_main, height_main), surface_main)

    SCREEN.fill((255, 255, 255))

    #blit main surface onto the screen
    SCREEN.blit(surface_main, (rect_main.x, rect_main.y))

    pg.display.update()

    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
        CLOCK.tick(30)
```